# Area of the circle

Tags: javascript, area

So I created a .js file to calculate the area of a circle and calculateArea() needs to calculate it.
The only thing that it does is the prompt(). What am I doing wrong?

```
function calculateArea(myRadius){
  var area = (myRadius * myRadius * Math.PI);
  return area;

  function MyArea(){
    calculateArea(myRadius);
    alert("A circle with a " + myRadius + 
          "centimeter radius has an area of " + area + 
          "centimeters. <br>" + myRadius + 
          "represents the number entered by the user <br>" + area +
          "represents circle area based on the user input.");  
  }      
}
var myRadius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the radius of your circle in cm:",0));
calculateArea(myRadius);
```

Comment: *Not calling function MyArea, You need to revisit function calculateArea .

Comment: As an aside, area is not measured in centimetres. (Your alert should probably say "square centimetres".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep function `MyArea` outside `calculateArea` and call `calculateArea` from within `MyArea`.

Call `MyArea` function instead of `calculateArea`.

Example Snippet:

```js
function calculateArea(myRadius) {
  return (myRadius * myRadius * Math.PI);
}

function MyArea() {
  var area = calculateArea(myRadius);
  alert("A circle with a " + myRadius + "centimeter radius has an area of " + area + "centimeters. <br>" + myRadius + "represents the number entered by the user <br>" + area + "represents circle area based on the user input.");


}

var myRadius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the radius of your circle in cm:", 0));
MyArea(myRadius);
```

PS: There are better ways to do this. Comment in case of questions.

Comment: Thank you!!
Yeah I think so too, but she asked to do like this :)

Answer (score 1):

this is a way for calculate the circle area

```
let Area, Environment;
let Radius = prompt("Enter Radius ");

function calculate(Radius) {
  CalEnvironment(Radius);
  CalArea(Radius);
}
function CalEnvironment(Radius) {
  Environment = Radius * 3.14 * 2;
  console.log("Environment is : " + Environment);
}
function CalArea(Radius) {
  Area = Radius * Radius * 3.14;
  console.log("Area is : " + Area);
}
calculate(Radius);
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to call `MyArea` outside of `calculateArea` but in this case, why not something like this?

```
function calculateArea(myRadius) {
    return myRadius * myRadius * Math.PI;
}

var myRadius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the radius of your circle in cm:",0));
var area = calculateArea(myRadius);

alert("A circle with a " + myRadius + "centimeter radius has an area of " + area + "centimeters. <br>" + myRadius + "represents the number entered by the user <br>" + area + "represents circle area based on the user input.");
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I had to do the other function. 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The following is a single function solution:

```js
function MyArea(myRadius){

 var area = Math.pow(myRadius, 2) * Math.PI;
  
 alert(
     "A circle with a " + myRadius +
     "centimeter radius has an area of " +
     area + "centimeters. \n" + myRadius +
     "represents the number entered by the user \n" +
     area + "represents circle area based on the user input."
 );
}

var myRadius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the radius of your circle in cm:", 0));

MyArea(myRadius);
```